# Connect Two ESP32 To Raspberry Pi

Tags: serial-port, raspberry-pi4, arduino-esp32

I want to connect 2 esp32 with the same manufacturer and product ID to a raspberry pi 4 by modifying the udev configuration file as follows:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", ATTRS{serial}=="0001", SYMLINK+="esp32-motores"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", ATTRS{serial}=="0001", SYMLINK+="esp32-sensores"
```

But since they are two identical devices, I have to find a way to differentiate both.
The ESP32 will not always be connected to the same port, and also the value of ATTRS{serial}=="0001" comes out the same on both devices.
If this is not possible, if you have another idea it also works for me, as long as there is no problem when reconnecting the ESP32 devices and it recognizes them separately

I have tried to look for another value of ATTR{} but I have not seen any that could help me differentiate both ESP32

Comment: 1) Serial interface is not a bus, it only connect on one-to-one basis. so you need to have two serial ports on your Raspberry if you chose to use Serial. 2)if you use two serial ports, the problem of differentiate the two esp32s go away. 3) alternative, use SPI or I2C for having RPI as master and ESP32 as slaves. 4) Each ESP32 has a unique mac address which can be used to uniquely identify each board by calling `uint64_t chipID=ESP.getEfuseMac();` or `WiFi.macAddress();`

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, I am very new to the subject.
If I connect two esp32 each via USB, how can I differentiate the Serial port and be able to communicate with both separately?